# How do I change my Roblox group description?

Tags: roblox

I have been trying to change the description in my Roblox group for a few weeks now, but it is giving the following error message:

> Unable to change group description.

Why is that? How can I change my group description?

Comment: This is most likely because roblox's servers are just horrible. Wait up a few minutes and try again. Try closing and opening the roblox website a few times, and try checking your wifi. On a side note, what's your group, I might join!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, ROBLOX's group system is terrible, gets overloaded by bots, and isn't a focus of ROBLOX engineers. Your best option is to repeatedly submit the change until it works; there is no sure-fire way to force a submission through.